# Disable stack trace in Mocha HTML reporter

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I am using *Mocha* for testing JavaScript on my simple web-page. Because of its simplicity, I think it is not worth to bother with *node/npm/webpack* stuff, so I do my testing in browser and use default mocha HTML reporter with `<div id="mocha"></div>`. But I am slightly annoyed because of large and often unnecessary stack traces in failed test cases. Is there any way to disable stack traces? And more generally, does *Mocha* HTML reporter has any configuration capabilities?

Answer (score 1):

You could hide all stacktraces by using the following CSS:

```css
.html-error > pre.error {
    display: none;
}
```

Or hide all reported errors (including stacktraces) by using

```css
.html-error, .error {
    display: none;
}
```

[The source code of the reporter](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/27688bca42a1bb15da82debaebc3fe13024ca7ce/lib/reporters/html.js#L188-L204) is the reason this works.

Comment: To be precise, `.test.fail > pre.error { display: none !important; }`

Comment: And this hides not only useless stack trace, but also useful assertion message

Comment: @hk_fellow Why is that? I'm not very familiar with the Mocha HTML reporter, but [this line](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/27688bca42a1bb15da82debaebc3fe13024ca7ce/lib/reporters/html.js#L191) suggests the selector should be `.html-error > pre.error`.

Comment: in my case else clause with `fragment('<pre class="error">%e%e</pre>', message, stackString)` takes place by some reason

Answer (score 0):

The default html reporter merges the AssertionError and Stacktrace together as you've noticed. You could create your own reporter by inheriting from the base HTML reporter and then delete the `test.err.stack` object before it emits in the fail event. A [walkthrough](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/Third-party-reporters) is available for creating a reporter.

There's a lot of third party reporters out there though, so you might want to check out some others before you invest the time. For example our reporter, [Mochaterial](https://github.com/netpoint-gmbh/mochaterial), displays the exception first and exposes the stacktrace once drilled down, which might be enough for you: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/brian-lagerman/pen/XwMPvw).